# 3D printer clog. Nozzle keeps getting screwed in crooked

Tags: filament, hotend, nozzle

My 3D printer has got a clog, and i think it  is because the nozzle hole has just recently started to only screw in crooked. I’m not sure how this happened. I have tried with multiple nozzles, but they all screw in crooked. Is there a way to fix this? Or is my only option to get a new hotend.

My 3d printer is an Ender 3

[image]

Comment: The technical term for this is "cross threading".

Comment: Note: if the threads on the heater block and /or nozzle have residual filament material on them it is easy to cross--thread the nozzle, especially when cold..   In this case it is easier to attach the nozzle with the heater hot so the filament material is soft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to purchase only the heater block for your hot end. The nozzle should thread in by hand without undue force. Having to use a wrench at the outset is an indication of a problem which should have stopped the attempt.

There are many sources for the "heater block for Ender 3" when used in a search. One such result is an [Amazon seller of three pieces for US$11.99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FTHJJQ8)

[image: amazon heater block for ender 3]

Image via linked site.